# Setting pointerkeys (numpad as mouse keys) parameters - acceleration, delay, etc

Tags: mouse, xkb

[X11 can convert the numerical keypad into a mouse pointer controller](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Accessibility#Mouse_keys) with

```
setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys
```

so that <kbd>KP_Left</kbd> moves the mouse pointer to the left, <kbd>KP_Right</kbd>
moves it to the right, etc.
However, I find the speed too slow. As I learned from [Mouse Keys Wikipedia
article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys#MouseKeysAccel),
there are five parameters to adjust the speed vs. time curve, which are said
to be configurable, so how to configure them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters can be configured using [`xkbset`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/xkbset/xkbset.1.en.html). The syntax is

```
xkbset ma mk_delay mk_interval mk_time_to_max mk_max_speed mk_curve
```

There is even `xkbset-gui` to help visualizing the resulting
speed vs. time curve as the parameters are tweaked.

[image]

Comment: What is your final parameter setting that was comfortable to you?

Comment: Mine is 1, 46, 6, 10, 1900 for the five parameters in this GUI. This mimics normal mouse really well. Don't forget to press "Apply Changes."

Comment: @zkytony, I do not use it much, but `xkbset ma 50 40 30 100 300` is what I have. Thanks for the remark on pressing "Apply changes", this window doesn't fit the height of my screen so I never knew there were buttons below!