# Seeking alternative to KeyNav(drive mouse with keyboard, for X)

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, vi-mode

as described in the title, I am seeking user-friendly alternatives to KeyNav.

I am a fan of CLI&TUI applications and stay on the terminal emulator most of the time,
where I can use the keyboard to get most of the job done.
However, I have to use the browser from time to time, which means I have to use the mouse(hmm, on a laptop, I only have the trackpad/touchpad) even I have the `vimnium extesion`.
I found it really hard to navigate my pointer to some small elements (e.g. the radio tag in a form).

So I'm wondering if there exists a fast&accurate way to simulate mouse movement/dragging/click.

#### links

- [github repository of keynav](https://github.com/jordansissel/keynav)
- [homepage of KeyNav (on the developer's blog)](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/)

Comment: Do you know of [mouse keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys)? You can adjust acceleration, max speed, etc. with [xkbset as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609367). Specifically for browsers, Qutebrowser is so damn awesome, give it a try.

Comment: I have not tried it but there is warpd